# How to convert a data-frame with status and date of the status changed into a data-frame with a data-frame with status_to, status_from and date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data-frame like this:

```
date        |  status
2020/01/01  |  A
2020/02/01  |  B
2020/03/01  |  c
```

I would like to convert it into something like this

```
status_from    |    status_to    |    date
A              |    B            |    2020/02/01 
B              |    C            |    2020/03/01
```

Assuming i do not know the name of status and there are way to many status to manually make a data-frame. I need something dynamic that will work with any data-frame with similar structure.
thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, convert the data frame to a list, make a new list according to your criteria, and convert the second list to a data frame.
However I am not sure what you want fill under 'status_to' and 'date' in the last row

```py
#df - the given dataframe 
list1=df.values.tolist()
list2=list()
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    list2.append([l[i][1],l[i+1][1],l[i+1][0]])
data_frame= pd.DataFrame(list2,columns=['status_from','status_to','date'])
print(data_frame)
```